# Launching an activity from another activity skips a lot (96) frames

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, fragment

I have an app which had two activities - LoginActivity (LA) and AppActivity (AA). As you have guessed, LA launches AA upon successful log. For the debugging purpose, I removed all the login logic and replaced it with the simple button to launch AA.

AA containes on Fragment which contain a viewpager with three views in which one of the view reads music file using Kotlin co-routines and populate into a Recyclerview. And other two views do something different which doesn't involve any kind of file I/O or api request, simple static UI.

Whenever I launch the app, I see skipping frames warning three time

1. On button click in LA to launch AA (40 frames skips)
2. On AA start (74 frames skips)
3. on AA complete load including child Fragment (38 frames skips)

I have tried android studio profiler to find out which one is causing this but I failed to do so.

```
 

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
    
            /*Permissions*/
            val permissions = listOf(
                    Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                    Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
            )
            validatePermission(permissions)
        }
    
        fun startActivity(view: View) {
            val intent = Intent(this, AppActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
    
        private fun validatePermission(permissions: List<String>) {
            Dexter.withContext(this)
                    .withPermissions(permissions)
                    .withListener(
                            object : MultiplePermissionsListener {
                                override fun onPermissionsChecked(p0: MultiplePermissionsReport?) {
    
                                }
    
                                override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(
                                        p0: MutableList<PermissionRequest>?,
                                        p1: PermissionToken?
                                ) {
                                    AlertDialog.Builder(this@LoginActivity)
                                            .setTitle(R.string.storage_permission_rationale_title)
                                            .setMessage(R.string.storage_permission_rationale_message)
                                            .setNegativeButton(
                                                    android.R.string.cancel,
                                                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialogInterface, i ->
                                                        dialogInterface.dismiss()
                                                        p1?.cancelPermissionRequest()
                                                    })
                                            .setPositiveButton(
                                                    android.R.string.ok,
                                                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialogInterface, _ ->
                                                        dialogInterface.dismiss()
                                                        p1?.continuePermissionRequest()
                                                    })
                                            .show()
                                }
                            }
                    ).check()
        }
```

Edit: I have found one of the problems with skipping frame. TTS
engine initialization inside onCreate causing problems. So I put it
inside a thread but still I have skipping frame problem though right
now it is not as high as before but still significant. Still three warnings for skipping frames.

```
    class AppActivity : AppCompatActivity(),  TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{
    
        private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    
     
    
    
        private var engine: TextToSpeech? = null
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_app)
            val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    
            val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
            val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
            val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
            // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
            // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
            appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
                    R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow), drawerLayout)
            setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
            navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    
            /*---Text to speech------*/
           
        }
    
        override fun onStart() {
            super.onStart()
             Thread(Runnable {
                     engine = TextToSpeech(this, this) 
             }).start()
        }
    
        override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
            return true
        }
    
        override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
            val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
            return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
        }
    
        override fun onResume() {
            super.onResume()
            realTimeData()
        }
     
    
        /*---Test Code-----------*/
        private var mHandler: Handler = Handler(Looper.myLooper()!!)
        private lateinit var mTimer2:Runnable
        private fun realTimeData(){
            mTimer2 = object : Runnable {
                override fun run() { 
                    mHandler.postDelayed(this, 200)
                }
            }
            mHandler.postDelayed(mTimer2, 200)
        }
    
        var mRand: Random = Random()
        private fun getRandom(): Double {
            return mRand.nextDouble() * 100
        }
    
        private fun playMessage(msg: String) {
            engine!!.speak(msg, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null)
        }
    
        override fun onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy()
            if (engine != null) {
                engine!!.stop()
                engine!!.shutdown()
                Log.d("TTS", "TTS Destroyed")
            }
        }
    
        override fun onInit(status: Int) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                val results = engine!!.setLanguage(Locale.US)
                if (results == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                        || results == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Not supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have also commented out viewPager and other two skip frames warnings are gone. Now, I don't want to remove viewpager so I am still debugging and will update here soon.

Comment: can you add `AppActivity`'s code

Comment: I figured out one of  three skipping frame warning. I was initializing TTS engine -   engine = TextToSpeech(this, this) in onCreate inside AppAcitvity which was causing 84 frames skips so I commented out and now I only get two warning for skipping frames instead of three.

Comment: Well then, now you don't need that?

Comment: No, I need that so I am putting it inside a thread. Right now I am trying to figure out other two warning for skipping frames.

Comment: If you can add the code, you can be helped

Comment: okay let me add it

Comment: @rahat I have updated my question. please read the new update too Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228125/discussion-between-rahat-and-greyfrog).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In few apps I faced the same issue,

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app)
    val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    
    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
    R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow), drawerLayout)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

   // Oncreate is the place for the initialization of things but if their initialization is CPU intensive then delaying them a bit will make things hassle-free.

   Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
          engine = TextToSpeech(this, this)
          observers()//perform other intensive task after a delay,e.g. loading a url on webview.
  },200)//delayed by 200ms, 
 }
```

When we start an activity the activity will be launched as soon as the oncreate finishes and onstart called, So we must let the `onCreate` finish smoothly, Which will let the activity be launched immediately.

Comment: I guess your method of delay initialization works. Thank you. I thought I wrote a some stupid code. Thank you again. Can I ask few more question in our chat?

Comment: I have added a question in our chat. please check whenever you can. Thank you

Comment: Sure, I'll check that out.

Comment: @Greyfrog, please checkout chat, I've mentioned some suggestions.

Comment: thank you so much again. I am reading the link that you have provided. Also one thing that I have figured out on my end which is, CPU usage remains zero until I interact with any element in the current view. Once interacted, CPU usage never goes back to zero, even if you don't interact with the UI anymore. So it is not the mediaplayer who is the culprit. I tried with the simple seekbar. When I swipe to the view, CPU usage remain zero but as soon as I adjust the seekbar, CPU usage goes up and remain up even if I don't interact with it anymore. Can you guess what could be the reason?

Comment: ok, keep the code same and try to test in one or two other devices, try to test in real device. Check if there is the same anomally.

Comment: I am always testing in real devices and I have already tested in my Lenove tablet tab4 10 and in my android ASUS zenfone 6 phone  and I am getting the  same result.